# Install PHPUnit 3.5.x without pear

Tags: php, phpunit

Since the phpunit channel was shut down in 2014, I am looking for a way to install phpunit version 3.5.x without pear. The only answers that I have found explain how to use it with composer, but version 3.5.x does not exist as a composer package.

I do have the 3.5.10 source code for PHPUnit, but I am struggling on how to install it so that I can use it as a command line tool.

Comment: the branch 3.5 haven't the related composer.json files that describe the needed dependences.. you can try to fork the repo and check to to fix it and use it as described [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/use-a-github-branch-as-a-composer-dependency). The dependency seems described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3.5#using-phpunit-from-a-git-checkout). Hope this help and that you find a better way. Good Luck!

Comment: Upgrade your tests and use a later PHPUnit 3 version, i.e. 3.7

Comment: Lets say, I cannot upgrade. I know that there are laster versions of course.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit 3.7 was the first version to support Composer and PHAR. With PHPUnit 3.5 you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use phpunit 4.8.* it supports composer and is very easy to install it. Using netbeans makes it even more easy because netbeans creates tests for you.

Put the following lines in the composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*"
},
```

Now update the composer via command and it will install. Using git it will be something like this.

```
composer update
composer install
```

To get the composer.phar

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Now configure phpunit and you're good to go.